# PYQT5 imported MDI Subwindow Scaled Up

Tags: pyqt5, mdi

I'm working on a gui tool-- I'm building it with Pyqt5. I'm speifically NOT using QT designer. I'm using an `MDI` widget to keep everyhing a bit tidier. 
Furthermore, so that my code is more crisp and less redundant, I'm building out each child window in a separate window in the same directory and then just importing the appropriate class from the individual files.

The problem is, whenver I import the subwindows, the are scaled up in the `MDI` subwindow. I am at a loss as to how I can address this. Has anyone expierenced something similar? I've added simplied code for my `MDI` subwindow below, followed by the code for one of the subwindows thta I'm importing. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMdiArea, QAction, QMdiSubWindow, QTextEdit
from Admission_Tool import *
from COPD_tool import *
from Discharge_Template import DischargeWindow
from Note_Template import *

class MDIWindow(QMainWindow):
    count = 0
    htntoolcount = 0
    copdcount = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size: 10pt; font-family: Times;')
        self.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{font-size: 10pt;}")
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size: 10pt;}")
        self.mdi.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.mdi.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        #####Setting up main Menu Labels and Buttons#####
        self.mainMenuWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.mmWidgetLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainMenuWidget.setLayout(self.mmWidgetLayout)
        self.mainMenuWidget.setWindowTitle("Main Menu")

        self.mmButton1 = QPushButton("Note Setup Tool", self)
        self.mmButton2 = QPushButton("Lab Entry Tool", self)
        self.mmButton3 = QPushButton("Follow Up Tools", self)
        self.mmButton4 = QPushButton("ROS Generator", self)
        self.mmButton5 = QPushButton("Physical Exam Generator", self)
        self.mmButton6 = QPushButton("Cardon Matrix", self)
        self.mmButton7 = QPushButton("Trilogy Matrix", self)
        self.mmButton8 = QPushButton("ASC Matrix", self)
        self.mmButton9 = QPushButton("Proactive Email", self)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton1)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton2)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton3)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton4)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton5)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton6)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton7)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton8)
        self.mmWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton9)
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.mainMenuWidget)
        self.mainMenuWidget.show()

        ##adding actions to main menu buttons##
        self.mmButton1.clicked.connect(self.noteSetupFunc)
        self.mmButton2.clicked.connect(self.admissionTool)
        self.mmButton3.clicked.connect(self.COPDToolFunc)


        self.setWindowTitle("Proactive Charting Tool")





    def noteSetupFunc(self):
        self.noteSUButtFuncWidget = NOTEWindow()
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.noteSUButtFuncWidget)
        self.noteSUButtFuncWidget.show()


        # Setting MAin Menu Widget for NOtes#
        # self.NOTEmainMenuWidget = QWidget(self)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        # self.NOTEmainMenuWidget.setLayout(self.noteMMWidgetLayout)
        # self.NOTEmainMenuWidget.setWindowTitle("Note Menu")
        #
        # self.NotemmButton1 = QPushButton("Admission", self)
        # self.NotemmButton2 = QPushButton("Discharge", self)
        # self.NotemmButton3 = QPushButton("Diag Testing", self)
        # self.NotemmButton4 = QPushButton("Acute Visit", self)
        # self.NotemmButton5 = QPushButton("Fall", self)
        # self.NotemmButton6 = QPushButton("Med Review / Comp", self)
        # self.NotemmButton7 = QPushButton("Coumadin", self)
        # self.NotemmButton8 = QPushButton("Noncompliance", self)
        # self.NotemmButton9 = QPushButton("Simple Note", self)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton1)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton2)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton3)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton4)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton5)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton6)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton7)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton8)
        # self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.NotemmButton9)
        # self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.NOTEmainMenuWidget)
        # self.NOTEmainMenuWidget.show()
        # self.NOTEMMButton2.clicked.connect(self.dcwindowFunc)

    def admissionTool(self):
        self.admitToolWidget = admitWindow()
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.admitToolWidget)
        self.admitToolWidget.show()

    def COPDToolFunc(self):
            self.copdToolWidget = COPDWindow()
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.copdToolWidget)
            self.copdToolWidget.show()
            MDIWindow.copdcount = MDIWindow.copdcount + 1


    def dcwindowFunc(self):
        self.dcwindowWidget = DischargeWindow()
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.dcwindowWidget)
        self.dcwindowWidget.show()

    def htnButton(self):
        self.htnsubwidgets = QWidget(self)
        self.htnMAinLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.htnLeftLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.htnRightLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        ##Adding secondary layours to main layouts##
        self.htnMAinLayout.addLayout(self.htnLeftLayout)
        self.htnMAinLayout.addLayout(self.htnRightLayout)

        ##Adding htnRightLayout widgets##
        self.htnLabel1 = QLabel("Date of last HTN Med change", self)
        self.htnDateEdit = QDateEdit(self)
        self.htnDateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 120, 45))
        self.htnDateEdit.setObjectName("Med_change_dateEdit")
        self.htnDateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate())
        self.htnDateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.htnQ2Label = QLabel("Med most recently changed?", self)
        self.htnQ2LineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.htnQ3Label = QLabel("Most Recent bP Measurement", self)
        self.htnQ3LineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.htnQ4Label = QLabel("Overall Bp Control?", self)
        self.htnQ4Combobox = QComboBox()
        self.htnQ4ComboboxList = ["Hypotension", "BP Well Controlled", "Some Hypertensive Episodes",
                                  "Regular Hypertension"]
        self.htnQ4Combobox.addItems(self.htnQ4ComboboxList)
        self.htnq5Label = QLabel("Resident's current meds?", self)
        self.htnq5LineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.htnCompleteButton = QPushButton("Complete", self)
        self.htnCompleteButton.setMaximumWidth(75)

        ##Adding Widgets to Left Layout##

        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnLabel1)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnDateEdit)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnQ2Label)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnQ2LineEdit)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnQ3Label)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnQ3LineEdit)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnQ4Label)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnQ4Combobox)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnq5Label)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnq5LineEdit)
        self.htnLeftLayout.addWidget(self.htnCompleteButton)

        ## Adding right widgets##
        self.htntextedit = QTextEdit()
        self.htntextedit.setMinimumWidth(200)
        ##Adding right widgets##
        self.htnRightLayout.addWidget(self.htntextedit)

        self.htnCompleteButton.clicked.connect(self.htnCompleteFunc)

        self.htnsubwidgets.setLayout(self.htnMAinLayout)
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.htnsubwidgets)
        self.htnsubwidgets.show()

    def htnCompleteFunc(self):
        self.htnTotalList = [self.htnDateEdit.text(),self.htnQ2LineEdit.text(),self.htnQ3LineEdit.text(),self.htnQ4Combobox.currentText(),self.htnq5LineEdit.text()]
        self.htntextedit.setText(f"The resient's most recent blood pressure med change ({self.htnTotalList[0]}) change was {self.htnTotalList[1]}. The residnet's most recent BP is {self.htnTotalList[2]}. The resdient is currently receiving {self.htnTotalList[4]}. Overall hypertension status: {self.htnTotalList[3]}")

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    font = QFont('Times', 10)
    app.setFont(font)
    mdiwindow = MDIWindow()
    mdiwindow.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()ere
```

An example of one of my subwindowss is as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMdiArea, QAction, QMdiSubWindow, QTextEdit
from Admission_Tool import *
from COPD_tool import *

class NOTEWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.notemdi = QWidget()
        self.setStyleSheet('font-size: 10pt; font-family: Times;')
        self.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{font-size: 10pt;}")
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size: 10pt;}")
        self.notemdi.setMaximumSize(500,500)


        #Setting MAin Menu Widget for this nested MDI#
        self.NOTEmainMenuWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.NOTEmainMenuWidget.setLayout(self.noteMMWidgetLayout)
        self.NOTEmainMenuWidget.setWindowTitle("Note Menu")

        self.mmButton1 = QPushButton("Admission", self)
        self.mmButton2 = QPushButton("Discharge", self)
        self.mmButton3 = QPushButton("Diagnostic Testing", self)
        self.mmButton4 = QPushButton("Acute Visit", self)
        self.mmButton5 = QPushButton("Fall", self)
        self.mmButton6 = QPushButton("Med Review/Comp", self)
        self.mmButton7 = QPushButton("Coumadin", self)
        self.mmButton8 = QPushButton("Noncompliance", self)
        self.mmButton9 = QPushButton("Weight Loss", self)
        self.mmButton10 = QPushButton("Simple Note",self)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton1)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton2)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton3)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton4)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton5)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton6)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton7)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton8)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton9)
        self.noteMMWidgetLayout.addWidget(self.mmButton10)
        self.NOTEmainMenuWidget.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    font = QFont('Times', 10)
    app.setFont(font)
    mdiwindow = NOTEWindow()
    mdiwindow.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please [fix your broken code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @QuartzymcManbun Please [edit] your post, provide a proper [mre] (note: it must be *both* minimal **and** reproducible), and explain more clearly what you mean by "scaled up", eventually providing images of the current result *and* the expected behavior. Besides, `setStyleSheet()` always overrides and clears any previous stylesheet set, calling it more than once on the same widget is just wrong.